# If $x'(t)$ is bounded for $x\geq0$ show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}{x(t)}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Assume that $x(t)$ is nonnegative for $t\geq0$ and $\int_0^\infty{x(t)\;dt}<\infty$. If $x'(t)$ is bounded for $x\geq0$, then show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}{x(t)}=0$.

---

I started with contradiction taking the limit is finite and strictly positive. Then it is easy to derive the contradiction. But the limit may be oscillatory too or diverging to $+\infty$.

Any help would be apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your contradiction proof? I think this question should be relatively straightforward, no?

Comment: $x(t)$ clearly can't diverge to $+\infty$ since $\int x(t)$ would not be less than $\infty$.

Comment: The contradiction is as follows :

Comment: Yes..I showed the exactly same thing but that works exactly when lim (t--> infinity) x(t)= d>0.

Comment: Can x(t) be oscillatory??

Comment: It could be, but what do you think would happen if the limit of the oscillations wasn't $0$?

Comment: I am not getting.can you give me the complete hint .Should I proof it directly or by contradiction??

Comment: Continious iff oscillation zero

Comment: I'm sure you could prove it by contradiction. Why don't you edit your question to include your work so far? My point about $x(t)$ being oscillatory was that if the oscillations were bounded below by a number, $\varepsilon>0$, you'd have $\int_0^{+\infty}\varepsilon\,\mathrm{d}t\leq \int_0^{+\infty}x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Furthermore, if $x(t)$ is oscillatory but doesn't tend to $0$, you'd end up with $\int_0^{+\infty} x(t)\not<\infty$

Comment: Yes..But how can we show tht x(t) is bounded below by some positiclve epsilon?

Comment: You need continuity for x(t). The condition on x'(t) may be sufficient. Without continuity, you could have (for example) x(t)=1 for all integers, but otherwise O.K. Then the limit won't exist. – herb steinberg 2 hours ago

Answer (score 6):

If $x(t)\not\to 0$, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that there exists a sequence $t_n\to\infty$ with $x(t_n)\ge \delta$. Taking a subsequence we can assume $t_{n+1}-t_n\ge \frac\delta M$. We have $|x'(t)|\le M$ so $x(t)\ge \frac\delta2$ for $|t-t_n|<\frac\delta{2M}$ and so $$\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}} x(t)dt \ge \frac{\delta^2}{4 M}.$$ Hence the integral must be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis in the question seems weird to me, but here is a related theorem.

**Lemma** (Cauchy criterion for improper integrals) Let $f : [a, b[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continue on $[a, b[$ where $-\infty<a<b\leq+\infty$. Then $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt$ converge iff $\forall\epsilon > 0$ $\exists A\in [a, b[$ $\forall  (x, y)\in([A, b[)^2$, $|\int_{x}^{y} f(t) dt| < \epsilon$.

Proof Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $F : x \mapsto \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$. Suppose that $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt$ converge. Then $F(x)\xrightarrow[x\to b]{}\ell\in\mathbb{R}$. So there exists $A\in [a, b[$ such that for all $x\in [A, b[, |F(x)-\ell| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Thus, for all $(x, y)\in([A, b[)^2$, $$|\int_{x}^{y} f(t) dt| = |F(y) - \ell +\ell - F(x)| < \epsilon.$$
Let's show the reciprocal. Let $(x_n)$ be sequence of $[a, b[$ converging to $b$. $(F(x_n))$ converge because it's a Cauchy sequence and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. We note $\ell$ this limit. Let $(y_n)$ be any sequence of $[a, b[$ converging to b and $\ell'$ be the limite of (F(y_n)). Let $(z_n)$ be the sequence defined for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by $z_{2n} = x_n, z_{2n+1} = y_n$. Since $(z_n)$ converge to $b$, $(F(z_n))$ converge to a real $\ell''$. Since $(F(x_n))$ and $(F(y_n))$ are sub-sequences of $(F(z_n))$, $\ell = \ell'' = \ell'$. We have therefore show that for all sequence $(y_n)$ converging to b, $(F(y_n))$ converge to $\ell$. Thus $F(x)\xrightarrow[x\to b]{}\ell$. Hence $\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt$ converge.

**Theorem** Let $a \in \mathbb {R}$ and $f$ be uniformly continuous over $[a, +\infty [$ such that $\int_{a}^{+\infty} f(t) dt$ converge. Then $ lim_{t\to+\infty} f(t) = 0 $.

Proof Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, +\infty [$, there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that for all $(x, y)\in [a, +\infty[, |x-y|<\alpha \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. On the other hand, since $\int_{a}^{+\infty} f(t) dt$ converge, via the criterion of cauchy, there exists $A\in [a, +\infty[$ such that for all $(x, y)\in([A, +\infty[)^2, |\int_{x}^{y} f(t)dt| < \frac{\alpha\epsilon}{2}$. Let $x>A$. $|f(x)| = \frac{1}{\alpha}|\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(x)dt| = \frac{1}{\alpha}|\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} (f(x)-f(t))dt + \int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt| \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}|\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} (f(x)-f(t))dt| + \frac{1}{\alpha}|\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt| < \frac{1}{\alpha}|\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} (f(x)-f(t))dt| + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$. Thus $f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{}0$

In the context of this question, $ x'(t) $ is bounded on $ [0, +\infty [$, which equivalent to x being lipschitz continuous. A lipschitz function is uniformly continuous, so $ lim_{t\to+\infty} x(t) = 0 $.

Answer (score -1):

## Incomplete proof (missing the case when $x(t)$ has no limit)

By contradiction, let $L \gt 0$ such that $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = L$.

Then, by definition $\forall$ $\varepsilon \gt 0$ exists $k \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that
$$\mid x(t) - L \mid \lt \varepsilon \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall \;\;t \geq k$$
Let $\varepsilon \in (0, L)$, then
$$0 \lt L - \varepsilon \lt x(t) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \forall \;\; t \geq k$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 < \int_k^\infty (L - \varepsilon)dt < \int_k^\infty x(t)dt < \infty$$
But this is a contradiction since $L - \varepsilon$ is a positive constant so $\int_k^\infty (L - \varepsilon)dt$ is not bounded.

Comment: This might prove  that the limit of $x(t) $ can't be greater than $0$ but doesn't examine the case of $x (t) $ having no limit.

Comment: Although I think you could extend this proof by using $\limsup $ in place of $\lim $, to cover the case of oscillatory functions with no limit.

Comment: @Jam I don't find a way to extending it. Could you please help?